# Change order margin is presented in facet_grid ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I've seen several answers on how to change the order of facets by reordering the factor levels. But I would like to change the order in which the margin is presented. So basically have `(all)` displayed on the left panel before `4`, `6`, `8`. Thanks in advance!

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars) + facet_grid(. ~ cyl, margins=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```r
mtcars2 <- rbind(mtcars, within(mtcars, cyl <- "(All)"))

qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars2) + facet_grid(. ~ cyl)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a very sophisticated solution, you always could edit your grobs structure:

```r
library(ggplot2)

gg = qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars) + facet_grid(. ~ cyl, margins=TRUE)

ggg = ggplotGrob(gg)

ggg$grobs = ggg$grobs[c(1,5,2:4,9,6:8,10:15,19,16:18,20:27)]

grid::grid.newpage()

grid::grid.draw(ggg)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible to rearrange grobs in a ggplot, but this should be considered a last resort because it is difficult to generalise the solution to accommodate changes in your data, and involves a fair bit of moving data around. But +1 for presenting the alternative